# How ro convert a string to timedelta type

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a column `evs['deur_open']`that looks like this:

```
0                      NaN
1                      NaN
2                      NaN
3                      NaN
4       21-7-2012 17:30:00
               ...        
1196    10-6-2019 18:00:00
1197    10-6-2019 18:30:00
1198    11-6-2019 16:00:00
1199    13-6-2019 18:30:00
1200    16-6-2019 17:00:00
```

Which are all strings. I would like to convert it to a timedelta object in order to do some operations, however when I use `pd.to_timedelta(evs['deur_open'], errors='coerce')` it converts all values to NaT, like this:

```
1      NaT
2      NaT
3      NaT
4      NaT
        ..
1196   NaT
1197   NaT
1198   NaT
1199   NaT
1200   NaT
```

I'm not sure why it does not convert the strings? Can anyone help or now how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: `timedelta` is for difference ot datetimes, do you need `pd.to_datetime(evs['deur_open'], errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: @jezrael On some conditions I would like to add 90 minutes to certain rows

Comment: If you remove `errors='coerce'`, it'll tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is necessary [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), so is possible add `minutes`, e.g. with [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
evs['deur_open'] = pd.to_datetime(evs['deur_open'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)

evs['new'] = evs['deur_open'] + pd.Timedelta(90 * 60, unit='s')
print (evs)
               deur_open                 new
0                    NaT                 NaT
1                    NaT                 NaT
2                    NaT                 NaT
3                    NaT                 NaT
4    2012-07-21 17:30:00 2012-07-21 19:00:00
1196 2019-06-10 18:00:00 2019-06-10 19:30:00
1197 2019-06-10 18:30:00 2019-06-10 20:00:00
1198 2019-06-11 16:00:00 2019-06-11 17:30:00
1199 2019-06-13 18:30:00 2019-06-13 20:00:00
1200 2019-06-16 17:00:00 2019-06-16 18:30:00
```

---

*EDIT:* For timedeltas by times remove dates and convert times strings only:

```
evs['deur_open'] = pd.to_timedelta(evs['deur_open'].str.split().str[1], errors='coerce')
print (evs)
     deur_open
0          NaT
1          NaT
2          NaT
3          NaT
4     17:30:00
1196  18:00:00
1197  18:30:00
1198  16:00:00
1199  18:30:00
1200  17:00:00
```

Comment: I would like to convert it to a timedelta object, not datetime as I want to do some time operations

Comment: @borisvanax - What is expected output e.g. `16-6-2019 17:00:00` in timedelta?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `to_datetime` instead ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)), then you calculate a timedelta with another datetime.

```
for dt in evs['deur_open']:
    pd.to_datetime(dt, format='%d-%m-%Y %h:%m%s', errors='coerce')
```

You string is not in a [timedelta format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) so you can't convert it into one.

*Timedeltas are absolute differences in times, expressed in difference units (e.g. days, hours, minutes, seconds). This method converts an argument from a recognized timedelta format / value into a Timedelta type.*